# Extract string data between specific points in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, nlp, regexp-substr

Example of Text:

```
PROCEDURE:                          Cryo balloon antral pulmonary vein
isolation and cavotricuspid isthmus ablation.

The patient is a middle aged and happy.
```

I am trying to extract "Cryo balloon antral pulmonary vein isolation and cavotricuspid isthmus ablation" from the text.

The Code I used:
`TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.Document_Text, 'Procedure:\s*(.*)\s*?\.',1,1,'inm',1)) as Text_Procedure_DESC`

But what I get is the whole note after 'Procedure:'

FYI:

- There are text fields Prior to and after the Procedure entry.
- There are multiple spaces and vary from note to note.

Not sure where I messed up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to make the `.*` pattern non-greedy by using `.*?`
- The `m` option is redundant (as you are not matching the start or end of lines)
- and you don't need the `TRIM` function.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(document_text, 'PROCEDURE:\s+(.*?)\.', 1, 1, 'in' , 1)
         AS Text_Procedure_DESC
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'PROCEDURE:                          Cryo balloon antral pulmonary vein
isolation and cavotricuspid isthmus ablation.

The patient is a middle aged and happy.' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | TEXT_PROCEDURE_DESC |
> | --- |
> | Cryo balloon antral pulmonary vein isolation and cavotricuspid isthmus ablation |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e4f03b7df32282e1bc78f999576f8dce)*